# Let &mut syntax

Tags: syntax, rust

It is possible to make the following binding in Rust:

```
let &mut a = &mut 5;
```

But what does it mean exactly? For example, `let a = &mut 5` creates an immutable binding of type `&mut i32`, `let mut a = &mut 5` creates a mutable binding of type `&mut i32`. What about `let &mut`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An easy way to test the type of something is to assign it to the wrong type:

```
let _: () = a;
```

In this case the value is an "integral variable", or a by-value integer. It is not mutable (as testing with `a += 1` shows).

This is because you are using **destructuring syntax**. You are pattern matching your `&mut 5` against an `&mut _`, much like if you wrote

```
match &mut 5 { &mut a => {
// rest of code
} };
```

Thus you are adding a mutable reference and immediately dereferencing it.

To bind a mutable reference to a value instead, you can do

```
let ref mut a = 5;
```

This is useful in destructuring to take references to multiple inner values.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about possibility of using destructing syntax in let bindings

Comment: tldr: assignment works like patern matching. Equal number of ampersands cancels out across the `=`. RHS can have more number of amperands.